# Unable to view custom UITableViewCell in iOS

Tags: ios, uitableview

I trying to display results in a UITableView in my iOS application using a custom UITableViewCell.  I am able to view the contents of my Array if I use the cell's textLabel, and detailTextLabel properties, but if I try to link the UITableView with the custom cell class to display the contents of the Array, I only get the default values from Interface Builder displaying in my table.

This is the relevant code that I have:

```
- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    static NSString *CellIdentifier = @"Cell";
    
    CustomTableCell *cell = (CustomTableCell *)[tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:CellIdentifier];
    if (cell == nil) {
        cell = [[CustomTableCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleDefault reuseIdentifier:CellIdentifier];
        
    }
    
    // Configure the cell...
    
    
    TransactionList *tList = [_list objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
/*    
    cell.transaction.text = tList.transaction;
    cell.type.text = tList.type;
    NSDateFormatter *formatter = [[NSDateFormatter alloc] init];
    [formatter setDateFormat:@"ddMMYYYY"];
    
    NSString *dateAsString = [formatter stringFromDate:tList.date];
    cell.date.text = dateAsString;

  */

//this code below displays the contents just fine, but the block of code above does not.    

    cell.textLabel.text = tList.transaction;
    cell.detailTextLabel.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@, %@", tList.type, tList.status];
    
    return cell;
}
```

The method below is what I have in my CustomTableCell class:

```
- (id)initWithStyle:(UITableViewCellStyle)style reuseIdentifier:(NSString *)reuseIdentifier
{
    self = [super initWithStyle:style reuseIdentifier:reuseIdentifier];
    if (self) {
        // Initialization code
        
        self.selectionStyle = UITableViewCellSelectionStyleNone;
        
        self.contentView.frame = CGRectMake(0, 0, 320, 80);
        
        _transaction = [[UILabel alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(5, 5, 80, 40)];
        [_transaction setBackgroundColor:[UIColor clearColor]];
        [_transaction setFont:[UIFont systemFontOfSize:12]];
        [_transaction setNumberOfLines:2];
        [_transaction setLineBreakMode:NO];
        [self.contentView addSubview:_transaction];
        
        _date = [[UILabel alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(100, 5, 80, 40)];
        [_date setBackgroundColor:[UIColor clearColor]];
        [_date setFont:[UIFont systemFontOfSize:12]];
        [_date setNumberOfLines:2];
        [_date setLineBreakMode:NO];
        [self.contentView addSubview:_date];
        
        _type = [[UILabel alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(200, 5, 80, 40)];
        [_type setBackgroundColor:[UIColor clearColor]];
        [_type setFont:[UIFont systemFontOfSize:12]];
        [_type setNumberOfLines:2];
        [_type setLineBreakMode:NO];
        _type.lineBreakMode = NO;
        [self.contentView addSubview:_type];
        
        
    }
    return self;
}
```

Where _transaction, _date, and _type are labels.  Here is a screenshot of my Interface Builder inside MainStoryboard:

[image]

I have tried changing the style from "Basic", to "Custom", to "Subtitle", but that does not help.  It only displays the default values of the table, and those settings change the way they appear, but at no point are the contents of my Array showing up in the table.  Can anyone see what it is I am doing wrong?  I really think the problem is something simple, but unfortunately I can't put my finger on it.

Thanks in advance to all who reply.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You don't show the 3 objects in the Master View cell. Change the 'Style' from Basic to Custom and drop in your objects.

In the 'Identity Inspector' make sure to rename the Class to 'CustomTableCell'.

Do the views (transaction, date & type) have properties in the CustomTableCell.h and are they  connected to the 'CustomTableCell' in IB?

Here's an image to point out the last two:

[image]

Comment: Thanks very much for your reply.  How, and from where would I "drop" in my objects?  Transaction, Date, and Type are simply labels, and are declared in the .h file, but not connected to the CustomTableCell in IB.  I am guessing they need to be?

Comment: Since they are declared, that's good. Now drop the objects (in my example - 2 UILabels, Master & Value) from the Object Library. Then you can control-drag to connect them to the CustomTableCell. In your case, the circle to the left of @property definition should be empty. Drag from that circle to the CustomTableCell object. 3 properties should appear. Select the correct one.